# AngularJS - ng-disabled is not disabling my element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-disabled

I´m trying to hide an option if the condition exists, but the option is still there.

Here is my code:

```
<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-disabled="disAplicar" ng-if="!hideBtnAplicar" ng-click="existenciaCero()">Aplicar Existencia Cero</a></li>
```

And my JS is:

```
$scope.disAplicar = $scope.datos.tipo == 'informativo' ? true : false;
```

Could you help me to find which the error is?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your title says you want to disable it (which is not valid for `a` elements), but your question says you're trying to hide it. Can you please clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I want to disable it

Comment: So the problem is it does not work for <a> elements. KK, is there a way to disable it?

Comment: I forgot to add this to my answer, but one of the CSS properties you'll want to be in your `disabled` CSS rule is [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It as easier than I thought. I just used ng-hide instead of disable and that´s it! Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simulate disabling an `a` element, you'll need to do it in two ways: styling and behavior. For the styling, have something like a `disabled` CSS class that applies programmatically using `ng-class="{ 'disabled': disAplicar }"`. That will make it look disabled, but to make it act disabled as well, make sure your `ng-click` function considers the same condition.

```js
$scope.existenciaCero = function() {
    if ($scope.disAplicar) {
        return;
    }
    // the rest of your code
}
```

And in the event that you're using `href` on the `a` instead of a click event, you'd want something like this, in addition to the disabled styling I mentioned:

```html
<a ng-href="{{ disAplicar ? '/someUrl' : '#' }}">My link</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case you should really use a `button` rather than an `a` tag, you could style the `button` like an `a` tag here with CSS.

```
<li role="presentation"><button role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" ng-disabled="disAplicar" ng-if="!hideBtnAplicar" ng-click="existenciaCero()">Aplicar Existencia Cero</button></li>
```